# How can I clear the current line of the Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, shortcuts, hotkeys

How can I clear the current line in the command prompt? (I'm using Windows 7.)

Too often, I enter a command, execute it, get many lines of output, then wish to enter another command. But before entering the second command, I press the up arrow key to review the first command, then I find I have to hold backspace for 30-or so characters. (I can't just press down again to get an empty line. Nor can I get it by pressing up again.)

Comment: @myrddim has it but that aside, some poor alternatives are keep tapping up until you have something short then hold backspace. another one is make the command be a bad command or filename, or rather, an "'sdfd' is not recognised as an internal or external command" so move the cursor a bit with left arrow and just tap a letter or don't and just tap a letter at the end, mess up the cmd input, then hit ENTER, get that error and the next line will be blank.

Comment: @barlop That is indeed a poor workaround! It only takes one keystroke. If you can't use the `Esc` key, you could use AutoHotkey to simulate it.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

The Escape (`Esc`) key will clear the input line.

In addition, pressing `Ctrl+C` will move the cursor to a new, blank line. This may be helpful as the input you just reviewed remains visible while you type the new command.

Comment: And if you want to clear the whole screen, you can use the `cls` command. :)

Comment: As a side note, on UNIX it's `ctrl+u`.

Comment: Which would be relevant if the question wasn't specifically targeted at the Windows 7 command prompt. :-) Also, I believe this is shell specific, as I am reasonably certain some shells have the same behavior as Windows when pressing `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: and how do you remove all the text so you can't scroll up?

Comment: @FutuToad the `clear` command will do what you ask.

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys on Windows it is `cls`

Comment: Note: the `CTRL+C` command will also exit any command line session you are having, i.e `python`, and return you back to the command line environment.

Comment: @AttitudeMonger That is a **common** command line utility behavior, but is not actually a feature of the command line itself. Many command line utilities do not exit on receipt of the Ctrl+C keystroke. It will not exit *any* command, but it is accurate to say it exits *many* commands.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks, I did not know that!

Comment: I use Ctrl + backspace to clear the current line, or ctrl + Home, if you press just `home` you go to the start of the line

Comment: Is it possible to set it to `ctrl+u` like in windows. I have to lift my hand to reach `esc`

Comment: ctrl+u on mac, thank you!

Answer (score 40):

Aside from the two that [Myyrddin](https://superuser.com/users/21951/myrddin-emrys) covered - `Esc` and `Ctrl+C` - there are also two more shortcuts related to clearing the current input in CMD.

**`Ctrl+Home` will clear all characters in the input *before the cursor*** (equivalent to `Ctrl+U` in Bash)

**`Ctrl+End` will clear all characters in the input *after the cursor*** (equivalent to Bash's `Ctrl+K`)

Both are fairly useful and, once internalised and gotten used to, could speed up editing in CMD by quite a bit.

Comment: I didn't know about these keystrokes; thank you. May you get the upvotes you deserve.

Comment: Same here. Being used to Bash I always wanted those. OP is my savior.

Comment: From bash(1): (Ctrl)+(X), (Rubout) is defined to be **backward-kill-line**; i.e., kill backward to the beginning of the line; i.e., the same as (Ctrl)+(Home) in Windows CMD. “Rubout” *may* be Backspace or Delete, so try (Ctrl)+(X), (Backspace) and (Ctrl)+(X), (Delete). Also, (Ctrl)+(U) is **unix-line-discard**; i.e., kill backward from the insertion point (cursor) to the beginning of the line; i.e., also the same as (Ctrl)+(Home).  (Ctrl)+(K) is defined to be **kill-line**; i.e., kill the text from the insertion point to the end of the line; i.e., the same as (Ctrl)+(End) in Windows CMD.

Comment: Just to be clear: (Ctrl)+(U) is a long-standing, general feature of Unix.  It works in old, non-Linux, non-GNU, non-bash systems; it works in `vi`; it works if you do `cat > file123`.  The others are specific to the bash command line.

Comment: Shift+Home and Shift+End selects the same as above, instead of deleting it.