# How to clear the current line in Cisco IOS quickly?

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

The title says it all. How can I clear the current line of text/commands quickly while using Cisco's IOS command line interface? If still clueless, [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/397189/) is very similar but it's for the Windows Command Prompt. However, I looking for a **shortcut-key combination** that works IOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ctrl + U** deletes the current line.