# How to change key binding for "Delete all characters before the cursor" in Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows, terminal, windows-terminal

I am trying to mimic the keybord shortcut behaviour of Bash to Windows Terminal.

In bash, "Ctrl+U" does "Delete all characters before the cursor",

In Windows Terminal, "Ctrl+Home" does it (https://superuser.com/a/1148782/976753),

How do I change the default key binding of "Ctrl+Home" into "Ctrl+U" for this in Windows Terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Terminal doesn't process such shortcuts.

In programs that use line-oriented input (such as Cmd.exe), it happens within Conhost (or its successor OpenConsole in WT's case), similar to how the Unix tty layer provides basic line editing for cooked-mode programs. Unlike Unix ttys, however, the shortcuts in Conhost/OpenConsole are [not customizable at all](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/main/src/host/cmdline.cpp#L1164).

In programs that use character-based input (such as PowerShell and Bash), all such shortcuts are handled by the program that receives input. PowerShell, for example, uses "PSReadline" which is practically a clone of the "readline" library used by Bash.

With PowerShell, use [`Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler?view=powershell-5.1) to bind Ctrl+U to the `BackwardKillInput` [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline_functions?view=powershell-5.1) (which should already be bound by default, but if it isn't, edit your `$Profile` file to make it happen).

Comment: Thanks, `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+u -Function BackwardKillLine` works for me! and `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+k -Function ForwardDeleteLine` !

Answer (score 1):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will map
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
to
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>,
but only for the executable `WindowsTerminal.exe`:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe WindowsTerminal.exe
^u::Send, ^{Home}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: I would recommend running AutoHotkey as a "logon" Scheduled Task instead of a regular startup item, as it needs to be elevated in order to spoof input to another elevated window – which is often the case for WT.